# How can I hide a cell on a specific breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, pure-css

I have the following base layout, which I now would like to transform into a responsive grid using pure css.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- ... --> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1">Navigation</div>

        <div class="pure-u-5-24">left space</div>

        <div class="pure-u-11-24">content</div>
        <div class="pure-u-3-24">ToC</div>

        <div class="pure-u-5-24">right space</div>

        <div class="pure-u-1">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how I can hide e.g. `<div class="pure-u-3-24">ToC</div>` on a specific breakpoint.

I had a look into the base file [pure.css](https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/pure.css) as well as the css containing the classes for the grid [grids-responsive.css](https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/grids-responsive.css). There seems to be no such thing as `.hidden-*-down` class known from Bootstrap. Also I coudn't find any (purecss-) utilities to accomplish this.

How can I accomplish my goal and hide an element on a specific breakpoint using PureCSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). ToC will hide under 728px.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:728px){
  .pure-u-3-24 {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1">Navigation</div>

  <div class="pure-u-5-24">left space</div>

  <div class="pure-u-11-24">content</div>
  <div class="pure-u-3-24">ToC</div>

  <div class="pure-u-5-24">right space</div>

  <div class="pure-u-1">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can add this css to your css files :

```
/* pure-hidden-md *
@media screen and (max-width:48em) {
.pure-hidden-md {display:none}
```

}

Now add class "pure-hidden-md" to anywhere:

```
<div class="pure-u-3-24 pure-hidden-md">ToC</div>
```